# Any way with Jenkins to select Spring Boot profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jenkins, gradle

My group is using Jenkins to build and deploy a Spring Boot application to AWS (Elastic Beanstalk).

For development I was selecting the desired profile for the environment I was in (DEV, QA) by setting the `spring.profiles.active` property in application.properties.

But dev-ops would like to set the property externally. Since the app is being deployed to a SpotInst managed EC2, I have no control over the environment.

I've been doing a lot of searching, but haven't as yet come across anything that fits this situation.

I'm using Gradle for building. The build generates a WAR file and is deployed to Tomcat.

Is there anyway to accomplish this with some sort of parameter substitution?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't an OS level environment variable called `spring.profiles.active` work?

Comment: The problem is that currently we're using spot instances on AWS (something I want to change). As such, you don't know what EC2 instance you'll be running on. This applies to our QA and production environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our devOps person discovered that we can set environment properties through AWS Beanstalk. By going to **Configuration** on the beanstalk instance and clicking on the Modify button under *Software*, scroll down and there is a section for environment variables. He put in *spring.profiles.active=qa* and that took care of it.

Since we have one beanstalk for each separate environment, it only has to be set once for each.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fit into your devOps process but there is very easy and clean way to achieve this.

Configure your `application.yaml` file like below:

```
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: ${SPRING_PROFILE:"dev"}
```

And while starting the application pass this parameter `SPRING_PROFILE` as command line argument. Note that `dev` is default value which will be used if the program doesn't find any matching command line argument or environment variable.

You can set the default value to the one you want to use for devOps while for all other purpose where you can control you can pass as argument.